# Isotope selector on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

isotpe filter menu link works fine, but when i change the menu to sidebar (cbFlyout) the link does now work. Since the cbFlyout sidebar menu link is dynamic i thought delegate selector will do the job but still same so the problem might be with isotope function.

My isotope function is:

```
  // bind filter button click
  $(document).on("click", "#filters a", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});
  });
```

Comment: is `$grid` variable an instance of isotope?

Comment: this is function is from the demo page, the JS file is minified i think so

Comment: ekaj_03 asked if you have declared an instance of isotope before the code show above `var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({ // options });`. Also, do you have any particular error in console when running this function/on click?

Comment: No enough information. Post a link of a jsfiddle